# Question about verifying if the credential rotation Lambda function for Secrets Manager successful

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I created a Lambda rotation function manually, configured it in Secrets Manager console (enabled the rotation, told SM to use this newly created function), everything looks fine so far but I don't know how to verify if the rotation is working now.

I found [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_db-rotate.html#tut-db-rotate-step5), I was going to follow step 4 'Verify Successful Rotation', but the command they provide is not for AWS CLI:

```
secret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id xxxxxxx | jq .SecretString | jq fromjson)
```

I got error if I tried in AWS CLI:

```
'secret' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Their approach is to use MySQL Client, is there a way to test it in AWS CLI or command prompt? Many thanks.

Comment: it says secret is nor recognized so I guess it is not even recognizing `secret=` text in your commands

Comment: @AshishModi I think they are commands used in MySQL Client, I don't want to use them, I prefer test it in aws cli or cmd, is there a way to verity the rotation?

Comment: The command they are running is a shell command. They are passing in the result of the call to secrets manager through `jq` to get the `SecretString`, and setting that value to `secret`. You could, then, follow that with `echo $secret` and see the value. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I'm using win10, I'm just wondering if I can just retrieve the secret in the SM console and save it as plain text, then check the secret again tomorrow (because I set it to rotate every day-for testing purpose), and see if the password changes tomorrow? Will this work? That commands basically doing the same thing I think....Also I can test if the rotation function is triggered(not sure how though)?

Comment: Sure. If you just run `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id xxxxxxx` it should return the secret object, including the secret string in plain text.

Comment: thanks, and is there a way to test the rotation Lambda? I mean if the rotation won't happen as we wish, how can we troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aws cli to verify that the credentials were rotated.

You should also verify using the MySQL client to verify that you can use the rotated credentials to access the database - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/tutorials_db-rotate.html#tut-db-rotate-step5

This command - secret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id xxxxxxx | jq .SecretString | jq fromjson) is a linux command to use the aws cli to retrieve the secret value and assigns it to a shell variable called 'secret'

Comment: Thank you, the thing is I still can't verify if the rotation is successful (or the rotation occurs), I retrieved the secret yesterday and set the rotation frequency to '1 day', I feel like I don't have to wait for a whole day to retrieve again, I found there's a button in SM console 'Rotate secret immediately', I pressed it and then got error ```Fail to rotate the secret "xxxx" A previous rotation isn't complete. That rotation will be reattempted.```.

Comment: When I use this command ```aws secretsmanager list-secret-version-ids --secret-id xxxx``` it gave me two ```VersionStages```("AWSCURRENT" & "AWSPREVIOUS") but the password in the secret (which I retrieved from console) hasn't changed, am I missing something?

Comment: @Cecilia do you see this message in the CW logs for the Lambda? - https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSMySQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py#L248